# Can I specify properties to be cached by NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, optimization, core-data

I am populating a `UITableView` with an `NSFetchedResultsController`. I'm formatting a lot of dates and concatenating descriptions from relationships to display each row but this will only ever need to be done once for each row. It's just a linear list of records in a fixed order.

If I wanted to add a property to my NSManagedObject subclass, say, `-(NSString*)dateAsDayName`, could I make `NSFetchedResultsController` cache this along with the normal entity attributes?

Comment: is the property you want to cache derived from other properties in the managed object?

Comment: a lot of it is via relationships - an item has many tags. I'd like to cache the list of tag names as a string when showing the index of all the items. Other than that it's a lot of date formatting that doesn't really need to be done more than once ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make it a transient attribute in your entity, core data will extend the benefit of caching to it. It will be called only once on fetch.

Comment: Note, that if you _do_ want to recalculate the value, you'll have to refresh the object with refreshObject:mergeChanges: